# Não consigo utilizar o webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-service, token-ajax

Eu tenho o seguinte `webservice`:

```
http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl
```

e nesse *WS* eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl/userLogin
```

que eu envio um usuário (sem senha) e ele me devolve um *token*.

Eu gostaria de consumir esse *WS* diretamente de uma página HTML com *jQuery*, porem não estou conseguindo.

custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var apiurl = 'http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl/userLogin';
  var user = 'teste';
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest();

  a.open('POST',apiurl,true),
    $.ajax({
       url: apiurl,
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify({user}),
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (data) {
         alert("Result: "+data);
       },
       error: function (xhr) {
          alert("Error");
       }
    });
});
```

Sempre me dá esse erro:

```
Failed to load http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl/userLogin: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500
```

No `F12` achei este erro:
[image: Printscreen com o erro 500]

O que está acontecendo?

Eu posso chamar o *WS* diretamente via *AJAX* ou eu preciso ter um servidor recebendo o *token* e eu pegar desse servidor?
Via *SOAP-UI* funciona.

EDIT:

Como o colega @Leandro Angelo comentou, faltava o envelopamento.
Fiz o seguinte:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var soapMessage = 
  "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://service.execbo.ws.framework.totvs.com'>" +
      "<soapenv:Header/>" +
      "<soapenv:Body>" +
      "<ser:userLogin>" +
      "<arg0>user</arg0>" +
      "</ser:userLogin>" +
      "</soapenv:Body>" +
  "</soapenv:Envelope>";

  var wsUrl = "http://IP:PORTA/wsexecbo/WebServiceExecBO?wsdl";
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "xml",
      url: wsUrl,
      data: soapMessage,
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
});
```

Agora parece que estou chegando em algum lugar, porem está acontecendo o seguinte problema:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header>
    </env:Header>
        <env:Body>
            <env:Fault xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
            <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                Unsupported content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
            </faultstring>
            </env:Fault>
        </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Fiz alguns testes colocando essas opções:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
contentType: "text/xml"
contentType: "application/xml"
```

Sem sucesso. Alguém já teve algo parecido ou sabe a origem desse tipo de problema?

Comment: Ah questão é como você está envelopando o seu post, dê uma olhada no soap ui e veja o formato que ele utiliza para o envio, inclusive se ele aceita json ou se você terá que montar um xml respeitando o contrato do ws

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, ajudou bastante porem ainda não consegui fazer funcionar. Incrementei o post inicial com as novas informações, se puder ajudar agradeço muito.